# Can Redis georadius function query hash data type

Tags: redis, hashmap, set, geospatial

I have a existing Redis database that include taxis hash. I want to query those hash using redis georadius() function to find the closest taxi in a 3 km radius. Do georadius() can handle hash data type ?

I have tried Redis Lab best practice with geospatial data: https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/indexing-patterns/geospatial/. I have been able to querie the data has "zset" using redis georadius(). So I understand how to use the function.

I can use the function hgetall() the taxi "hash" throught Redis Desktop Manager.

```
HGETALL taxi:test
 1)  "mytaxi"
 2)  "1507737272 45.61155 -73.8404 free phone 2"
```

```
GEORADIUS taxi -73.608000 45.511885 1 km WITHDIST
>>

GEORADIUS taxi:29yqx6ataxi -73.608000 45.511885 1 km WITHDIST
>>
```

Using redis georadius() I get no result.

I expect to confirm that redis georadius() do not support "hash" data type or that I have to process a manipulation to convert the data type or that I mist the syntax to query "hash" using georaidus() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GEORADIUS` only operates on Geo Sets (a.k.a. Sorted Sets).

Comment: Thank @Itamar Haber for your response. Whould you say there is a way to do a goespatial closest search on "hash"?

Comment: No, but you can use both a Hash (for storing information about the taxi) and a GeoSet (for indexing its position).